# On Cohen-Macaulay schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohen-macaulay-rings

I know that the irreducible components of a Cohen-Macaulay (CM) scheme don't need to be Cohen-Macaulay. But what happens if we assume that that the irreducible components are CM, what can we say about the scheme? More precisely my question is the following:

Let $X$ be a reduced scheme of finite type over a field $K$ and suppose that the irreducible components of $X$ are Cohen-Macaulay. In which case is the scheme $X$ itself Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: That is not always true.  A union of two linear $2$-planes in $\mathbb{A}^4$ whose intersection equals the origin is not Cohen-Macaulay, nor even $S2$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! Do you know if it is possible to add some condition to the intersection of the components such that we end up with a CM scheme? E.g. if the components intersect transversally.

Comment: Jason’s example has transversal intersection.

Comment: A perhaps even simpler example is the intersection of a line with a plane (in any manner). Or more generally any two irreducible components of different dimensions.